# Diagonal sawtooth-looking print issue

Tags: print-quality

I got this surface error in my prints using an Ender 5 with BLTouch.

[image: 3D print with surface error]

My printer prints a lot and is quite old.

Is it possible that the steppers are done?

Comment: Huh! That’s a new one. I can’t see from the picture, but from the top, are the ridges like a zig zag, or are they bulges? Zig zag would be a problem in the XY motion, bulges would be a problem with the extruder or the Z motion, like if the hotend is bouncing up and down.

Comment: Hi, sometime the nozzle rattles over the print. Maybe it is a problem with the z steps.

Comment: :/ missing force while extruding. Too hot the extruder...